# p css isn't working when I put it in a list

Tags: html, css

This is what should happen:
[image]

This is what is happening:
[image]

THE CSS

```
p {
        background: #efefef;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        padding: 5px 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;  
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-table;
        color: #010101;
        text-align:center;
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-right: 20%;
        z-index: -1;
}
```

THE HTML

```
<p>
        <ul>   
                <li><a href="03.html">Spain 2003</a></li>
                <li><a href="04.html">Costa Rica 2004</a></li>
                <li><a href="05.html">Spain & Portugal 2005</a></li>
                <li><a href="06.html">Spain, France, & Italy 2006</a></li>
                <li><a href="07.html">Peru 2007</a></li>
                <li><a href="08.html">Edinburgh, London, Paris, & Barcelona 2008</a></li>
                <li><a href="09.html">Costa Rica 2009</a></li>
                <li><a href="10.html">Australia, New Zealand, Hawaii, & Fiji 2010</a></li>
                <li><a href="11.html">Spain & Morocco 2011</a></li>
                <li><a href="12.html">Rome & Greece 2012</a></li>
                <li><a href="13.html">Costa Rica 2013</a></li>
        </ul>
</p>
```

Comment: This is impossible to debug without HTML and/or a jsfiddle.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?   Your first screenshot shows an image viewer in the center.   Your second shows a text list, which is what your code is above.   You can get the image viewer from what you have shown us here...

Comment: The problem is that the p css isn't working when I add a list to it, as in the block in the first picture. (ignore the image viewer, just testing stuff out)

Comment: You can't put a `ul` (unordered list) inside a `p` (paragraph) tag. A `p` tag is for paragraphs, and a `ul` tag is for a list. If you are using `p` purely as a container, use `div` instead of `p`.

Answer (score 1):

Then the first image would be the answer for you! :/ Why don't you show us how are you writing the thing up?

That's just the CSS error, you are just creating the `psd` and trying to convert it to `HTML`? That's not gonna happen.

> p css isn't working when I put it in a list

You should not add `p` to a list (`li`). Here is an example for you[image]

You cannot add the `p` to the `li` its illegal in HTML.

However the only issue that was a messup in UI!

The first image is showing some kind of a slideshow viewer, but the second one is showing a list. Well in my opinion it actually is working. You are saying you have just put the item in a list **Then it is showing a list**, what's missing there? That's how the list shows up!

If you want to show the images in a list, then try to add the image there in the list :) And just add some codes of CSS, that will work!

Good luck, cheers!

**Try providing some code:** Give us some example or the code that you have, we can fix it! But we cannot give you opinions, its off-topic here. Sorry :(

**Addition:**

```
<p>
    <ul>   
            <li><a href="03.html">Spain 2003</a></li>
            <li><a href="04.html">Costa Rica 2004</a></li>
            <li><a href="05.html">Spain & Portugal 2005</a></li>
            <li><a href="06.html">Spain, France, & Italy 2006</a></li>
            <li><a href="07.html">Peru 2007</a></li>
            <li><a href="08.html">Edinburgh, London, Paris, & Barcelona 2008</a></li>
            <li><a href="09.html">Costa Rica 2009</a></li>
            <li><a href="10.html">Australia, New Zealand, Hawaii, & Fiji 2010</a></li>
            <li><a href="11.html">Spain & Morocco 2011</a></li>
            <li><a href="12.html">Rome & Greece 2012</a></li>
            <li><a href="13.html">Costa Rica 2013</a></li>
    </ul>
</p>
```

Well this is working! :) You can see the list there, now you can do this:

```
ul li {
 display: inline;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}
```

Then add the images there, this way you will get the images thumbnails like you have there,

And above this list, show another image which would be used as the main or whatever-you-call-the-big-image. And you will have the one you are having in the first image. And then bind them all up inside one div and set `border` `width` heightpadding` and other properties to give it a kick start.

**In my opinion:** The code you're having is working. Its perfect!